# pbuilder --build --no-clean-after

Tags: debian, pbuilder

I want `pbuilder` on debian to create a chrooted env, install build dependencies, build a package and then launch a shell and let me analyze the build directory.

For example, if I run:

```
sudo pbuilder --build snacc_1.3.1-5.dsc
```

there's a file:

```
/var/cache/pbuilder/build/20352/tmp/buildd/snacc-1.3.1/compiler/back-ends/c-gen/util.c
```

It gets deleted after.

`mock` for `rhel` has the option `--no-clean-after`. Can't find a similar option in `pbuild`.

There's `--preserve-buildplace`, but it does something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked the `/usr/lib/pbuilder/pbuilder-buildpackage` which does the main part, and there seems no way to avoid cleaning up without modifying the script itself.

But maybe helpful for you: The hook "B" is called after building as stated in `man pbuilder`, section "--hookdir".

> B<digit><digit><whatever-else-you-want> is executed after build system finishes building, successfully, before copying back the build result.

I use the following script in my configuration for a shell at this stage:

~/.pbuilderhooks/B10shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
# invoke shell if build fails.

if [ -n "$PBSHELL" ]; then

apt-get install -y --force-yes nano less bash
cd /tmp/buildd/*/debian/..

echo "pbuilder-$OS-$DIST-$ARCH" >/etc/debian_chroot

cat <<.e

----------------------------------------

OS:   $OS
DIST: $DIST
ARCH: $ARCH

pbuilder-cmd: $PBCURRENTCOMMANDLINEOPERATION

========================================
Entering DEBUG shell:

.e
/bin/bash < /dev/tty > /dev/tty 2> /dev/tty

else
  echo 'I: If you want a shell, set envvar PBSHELL=1' >&2
fi
```

To activate the shell, call pbuilder like this:

```
PBSHELL=1 pbuilder --build ...
```